# How to Not Show the Editor Group's Side Buttons in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get my VS Code appearance to be as minimalistic as possible. Right now, I would like to not show the *editor groups' helper buttons* because they take space and I don't really use them anyway — I mostly use command line tools and shortcuts for them.

What is (or are) the configuration(s) to get rid of these buttons?

[image: editor group with side buttons]

Comment: And see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/46403

Comment: Quite bizarre that the VS Code team hasn't yet implemented a simple solution to such a highly requested feature, it doesn't even seem that hard.

Comment: I agree, a toggle with default on so that some people aren't surprised by the change.